# linux commands mkdir, rm -r and ln -s -T in processing phase of IZPack 5.0.0

Tags: linux, jboss7.x, mkdir, izpack, ln

I am using JBoss 7.1.1 application server with my java application in linux and have successfully been able to start JBoss during the processing phase of IZPack(processSpec.xml).  I was getting "command not found" messages during the processing phase.  I decided to get rid of all the comments and the messages went away.  However, when I execute the uninstall, mkdir and ln -s -T appends a "?" at the end of the filename and link.  Is this a bug?  The rm -r successfuly removes the jboss script at /etc/init.d, but fails to remove the jboss-as.conf file at /etc/jboss-7.1.1.Final.  I have jboss home at /usr/share.  rm -r fails to remove /standalone and /modules.  I get a popup during the uninstall stating administrative priveleges are required to remove /standalone and /modules.

All input is appreciated.

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

rm(1) man page notes :

```
Otherwise, if a file is unwritable, standard input is a terminal, and the -f or --force option is not given, or the  -i  or
--interactive=always  option is given, rm prompts the user for whether to remove the file.  If the response is not affirma-tive, the file is skipped.
```

That appended `?` after filename sounds like the prompt.

You're trying to remove files, that's readonly.  `rm -r` is failing to remove things, probably because you don't own /standalone and /modules.  Presumbably you needed "administrative privileges" to get things installed where they are in first place.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try rm -rf.  As far as why the script cannot remove /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, I am suspecting the jboss service may still still be running even though I did not get any errors from chkconfig jboss-as-7.1.1.Final off and service jboss-as-7.1.1.Final stop.

Comment: No, in UNIX you can delete things that are open, it's actually common to do that to avoid rw temporary files getting left around.  So long as they're open, they are accessible via the opened file pointer, but the instant they're not..    they are gone.